# How can I add a save_screenshot to If statement?

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I want to take a screenshot if the login button is disabled or not. Where can I add the `save_screenshot` to be able to do this?

```
def is_login_button_disabled(self):
        self.disabled_login_button = self.browser.find_element(*self.login_button_disabled)
        if self.disabled_login_button.is_displayed():
            print("Login Button Disabled")
        else:
            print("Login Button Enabled")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one line like:

```
def is_login_button_disabled(self):
    self.disabled_login_button = self.browser.find_element(*self.login_button_disabled)
    if self.disabled_login_button.is_displayed():
        # take screen shot
        self.browser.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
        print("Login Button Disabled")
    else:
        print("Login Button Enabled")
```

Edit:

You should take extra variable like `image = "image"` and `count=0` variable, which is increment each time after the screenshot is took

```
image_screenshot = image + str(count) + ".png"
self.browser.save_screenshot(image_screenshot)
count+=1
```

Note:

**Define image and count as global variable or pass as parameter while call function and define in main function like:**

```
def main():
   image = "image"
   count = 0
   self.is_login_button_disabled(image,count)
```

Comment: Thanks bharatk. It is possible for the screenshot to be saved as something different each time or would I need to change the name of it manually each time I input this line?